# How to delete user account when user clicks delete button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to delete user account when user click delete button.

```
import { getAuth, deleteUser } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

deleteUser(user).then(() => {
  // User deleted.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error ocurred
  // ...
});
```

in this source code -->**UserAuthContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import  auth  from '../Firebase/firebase';

export const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  function logIn(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function signUp(email, password) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
  }
  function googleSignIn() {
    const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      console.log('Auth', currentUser);
      setUser(currentUser);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  function forgotPassword(email) {
    return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email, {
      url: `http://localhost:3000//startForm`,
    })
  }


  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user, logIn, signUp, logOut, googleSignIn, forgotPassword }}
    >
      {children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
  return useContext(userAuthContext);
}
```

and this is delete button ( this button in another page NOT in UserAuthContext.js )

```
<Button variant='contained' style={btnStyle} onClick={handleDelete} >
 Delete
</Button>
```

what should I have in **handleDelete** ( this func in the same page with delete button )

```
 async function handleDelete(){
 
  }
```

Edit after I add **deleteUser(auth.currentUser)** in handleDelete function

```
 async function handleDelete(){
           try {
               await deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
               navigate('/');
           } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
           }
  }
```

it shows error **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'delete')**

Answer (score 0):

Literally, `deleteUser(getAuth().currentUser)` this will delete a user account if he is freshly logged in. I don't know what more information you need.

Comment: So 1. I have to import deleteUser from "firebase/auth"; in UserAuthContext.js right? and then 2. where to implement deleteUser(getAuth().currentUser) ? seem not clear for me

Comment: 3. how deleteUser(getAuth().currentUser) link to my delete button when user click. very appreciated for helping me

Comment: @aozroveymo You can implement it wherever you want, the best way is in component where you want to delete user. You don't need any `userAuthContextProvider()`.

Comment: @aozroveymo Firebase V 9 is not an Object-Oriented Programming. It is a functional way. Just make sure in your app to first trigger `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`. And then abuse its functions however you want.

Comment: @aozroveymo So you no need to `export const auth = getAuth()` just use `getAuth()` where you need it.

Comment: it shows error as I edit above so I don't know why

Comment: @aozroveymo I have no clue where you have that "delete" value. I wrote in answer that first you need to reauthenticate user using email a password and right after that delete user, or it won't work.

Comment: I get it right now, if user log out then user cannot log in again. Iam so nervous at the first time haha